# What's the point of an explicit database transaction in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, domain-driven-design

In my project, dependency injection will instantiate DomainContext (an Entity Framework 6 `DbContext`) for every request. I'm wondering what would be the right course of action, regarding transactions. I'm aware that `SaveChanges` will use a transaction internally.

Should I be worried about possible changes that are left behind in the `DomainContext`?

I thought that using an explicit transactions might shield me from this case, as in:

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    private DomainContext db;

    public FooService(DomainContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void MergeEntities(Entity source, Entity target) 
    {
        using (var uow = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            // merge source into target

            db.SaveChanges();

            uow.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I should just use this instead, it might give me the same protection:

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    private DomainContext db;

    public FooService(DomainContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void MergeEntities(Entity source, Entity target) 
    {
        // merge source into target

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know if this is correct or not, but as far as I knew transactions only affect the database state. Any context operations are not bounded by the transaction so if you wrap the merge in a transaction, you can still end up with a mess if the merge operation goes wrong - in which case you should discard the context and start again. At this point nothing has hit the DB - the work is done in the DB during `SaveChanges`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DbContext.SaveChanges()` is atomic and will automatically execute under it's own transaction.  So your second example is sufficient.

`DbContext` and the `SaveChanges()` method is an implementation of the Unit of Work pattern in Entity Framework.

`Database.BeginTransaction()` creates the transaction on the underlying database and also allows the caller to set an optional `IsolationLevel`. It's a transaction at a completely different level in the architecture. It's something I probably would never use, as I don't like to have any business logic in the database, but I bet there's plenty of scope for it's use in legacy systems.

Comment: Alright, so in what situation would the first example be appropriate?

Comment: I'd use a transaction when I'm not using EF and making changes to multiple tables.  I'd also use transactions when making changes across multiple contexts and other sources that take part in transactions.  You may need to enable to MSDTC service when using transactions across more than one source.

Comment: Right, so I get this, but what is then the point of using `db.Database.BeginTransaction()`? It seems to me like there is no use case for it; but it would never have been added to the framework if that is really the case.

Comment: `Database.BeginTransaction()` creates the transaction on the underlying database and also allows the caller to set an optional `IsolationLevel`.  It's a transaction at a completely different level in the architecture.  It's something I probably would never use, as I don't like any logic the database.  But I bet there's plenty of uses for it in legacy systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Unit Test to prove that EF uses transaction. 
Try to insert several rows, and one of the row has invalid data. 
Then, use SaveChanges() to save those multiple records to database.
If all or some records were rolled back, then EF uses transaction.

Or, unit of work or transaction scope is good.
Or you can also use code below to check changes on DbContext:
    DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added
    || e.State == EntityState.Modified
    || e.State == EntityState.Deleted);

Comment: I see what you are saying, I know how transactions work, but what is the added value of `db.Database.BeginTransaction()`? It seems to me like there is no use case for it; but it would never have been added to the framework if that is really the case.